# How do I handle these pandas error messages?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Often when using pandas I get UserWarning and PerformanceWarning messages like these:

```
C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py:558: UserWarning: merging between different levels can give an unintended result (2 levels on the left, 1 on the right)
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)

C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py:558: UserWarning: merging between different levels can give an unintended result (1 levels on the left, 2 on the right)
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)

C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:2530: PerformanceWarning: dropping on a non-lexsorted multi-index without a level parameter may impact performance.
  obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
```

When writing large scripts, I find difficult to know what in my code is the source of the warning.

So how can I figure out what line of my source code generates the warning messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach that I often use is to configure the `filterwarnings()` method in the `warnings` package to filter the warnings to raise which will enable you to debug them (e.g., using `pdb`). To do this you just need to `import` the `warnings` package and then set the `filterwarnings()` method on `warnings` to watch and raise specific warnings, like this:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('error', category=UserWarning)
warnings.filterwarnings('error', category=PerformanceWarning)
```

You can also just configure `warnings` to raise any warning, like this:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('error')
```

You can learn more about using `pdb` here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Comment: Good catch! Sorry I didn't catch it myself.

Comment: Initially I used the second option, as `PerformanceWarning` is not defined in the `Warning` classes of the package.
  Since the PerformanceWarning bothers me most, I've looked for a way to filter just that, and found this tip from one of pandas contribuitors:
`warnings.filterwarnings('error',category=pandas.io.pytables.PerformanceWarning)`
where I found:
 https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3622

Comment: Couldn't edit the comment so just removed and added another, sorry for the mass and thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Anytime my friend! :)

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to resolve the underlying issues, you can use the `-W` option on the command-line to turn the warning into an error, which will give you the full stack trace.

From the command-line documentation:

> -W arg : warning control; arg is action:message:category:module:lineno
>           also PYTHONWARNINGS=arg

E.g., to trap the warnings that start with "merging between different levels...", you could run:

```
python -Werror:merging myscript.py
```

Comment: This is a good tip and a better answer. It helped me identify the specific line of code which triggered the PerformanceWarning mentioned in the question. I changed the word `merging` to `dropping` to find it. `python -Werror:dropping myscript.py`